# How to switch to new compiler in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I was using Python 3.9 for long. But I got some problem and I decide to install Python 3.11 for coding, but vscode still in Python 3.9.

I don't know how to change the compiler to Python 3.11 (I added it into Path). So how can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you read the docs? [Work with Python interpreters - Using Python Environments in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_work-with-python-interpreters) or [Select a Python interpreter - Get Started Tutorial for Python in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_select-a-python-interpreter)

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask] for tips like starting with your own research.

Comment: @Luciana There's no code involved here...

Answer (score 0):

you can specify to VS Code the version of python to use with the interpreter

In settings.json (Here a virtual environment):

```
"python.defaultInterpreterPath": "${workspaceRoot}/venv/"
```

Or at the bottom left of VS Code, you can select the version of python that is installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use shortcuts **"Ctrl+Shift+P"** and type **"Python: Select Interpreter"** to choose your python interpreter.